# Get values of a cell using lists in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to implement a predicate in prolog where given any sample table with data, the contents of the table indices [+I, +J] should be printed on the terminal. In this case,
Here is the prototype of the predicate: 
`get_table_values_cell([+I,+J],+Table,-ContentsL)`

Sample output:

```
?- table(sample_table4,Data),get_table_values_cell([3,2],Data,CL).
Data = [[["11"], ["21"], ["31"], ["41"]], [["12"], ["22"], ["32"]],
[["13"], ["23"]], [["14"]]],
CL = ["32"].
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you describe what you've tried and ask about where you are specifically stuck?

Comment: I'm stuck as to how to go through the given list to the indices given (in this example, to the cell "coordinates" of [3,2]) and print out the value (which is "32" in this case) in that location.

Comment: Read the Prolog documentation regarding predicate `nth0/3` or `nth1/3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be easily solved with `nth0/3` or `nth1/3` (built in predcates), for instance in this way:

```
get_table_values_cell([R,C],L):-
    Data = [
           [["11"], ["21"], ["31"], ["41"]], 
           [["12"], ["22"], ["32"]],
           [["13"], ["23"]], 
           [["14"]]
           ],
    nth1(R,Data,L1),
    nth1(C,L1,L).

?- get_table_values_cell([3,2],CL).
CL = ["23"].
```

To solve it without using `nth0/3` or `nth1/3`, you can write your own "find" (here called `getElement1/4`) predicate in this way:

```
getElement1(C,C,[H|_],H):- !. %the cut is not mandatory    
getElement1(Current,Max,[_|T],Lout):-
    Current < Max,
    C is Current+1,
    getElement1(C,Max,T,Lout).
```

and then

```
getElement([R,C],L):-
    Data = [
           [["11"], ["21"], ["31"], ["41"]], 
           [["12"], ["22"], ["32"]],
           [["13"], ["23"]], 
           [["14"]]
           ],
    getElement1(1,R,Data,L1),
    getElement1(1,C,L1,L).

?- getElement([3,2],L).
L = ["23"]
```

BTW i suggest you to use built in predicates.